# Am I pronouncing "button" correctly, in an American accent?

Tags: american-english, american-accent

I recorded my voice saying "button" in American English.

Could you please tell me if I am saying it correctly?

http://www.filedropper.com/untitled_77

Comment: Download isn't working for me - keep getting "file of unknown size."  Tried my windows PC and my Android phone.

Comment: @user3169 They seriously are, imo! :D They can reveal all kinds of interesting and unusal things that are really useful and interesting for other readers/listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Native American English speaker here, Midwestern accent, also known as "General American".)

I think you basically got it.

You've got the glottal stop for the *tt,* and I *think* you've even got your tongue in the right place, positioned to make a proper *t* as the glottal stop begins but not actually doing it.

You've also got a truly vocalic *n.* That's probably the hardest thing to get right, or to believe: that the *n* really is the vowel for the second syllable, with no vowel between the *tt* and the *n.*

It sounds like you're experimenting with a lot of variations, so this comment might be irrelevant, but there shouldn't be much delay between the glottal stop and the *n.* In a lot of your experiments, you inserted a pretty long delay.

Also, the stress should be clearly on *butt-* and not on *-on.* There shouldn't be much effort in the *-on.* Also, it's excellent that you're descending in pitch from the *butt-* to the *-on.* If you really want to sound American, try experimenting with a wider interval. In a sentence, of course, these pitches will vary, but as I'm saying *button* to myself over and over right now, there seems to be a drop of a perfect fifth from the first syllable to the second! I could be wrong about that, but checking against a piano, my pitches seem to be: F3 to B♭2. I think you're basically going from around E3 to C3. You should probably listen closely to a recording of an American saying *button* (out of context, not in a sentence), take note of the pitch, and then experiment some more.

For comprehensibility, correctness, and clarity, your rendition leaves nothing to be desired. The only thing "Unamerican" about it is the pitch, and even that's pretty close.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe that I said that word correctly, and for the delay, I in purpose did that in order to show u the word, Thank you very much